# How do I make an MS Access Query to show totals by ID

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I have been trying to make a MS Access database to record and report on my organization's volunteer hours. Our volunteers give us monthly timesheets, which we input through a form as we receive them. I would like a report that takes the unique ID of each volunteer and combines every entry into one row.

The names are being drawn from another table that contains the contact information for everyone we work with. The contact info table has a primary key ID, and the volunteer stats table has the same ID connected by a one-to-many relationship. The volunteer stats table ID does NOT have referential integrety and has multiple entries associated to each ID.

Right now the table looks something like this:
[image]

And I want the end output to look like this:
[image]

So far all I have been able to find is tutorials on how to add a total row, which isn't helpful in this case. We need to know how many hours EACH volunteer put into EACH program.

I started by trying to set up a report with the report wizard, but couldn't find a way to make it display each name only once.

I have tried using a crosstab query to combine them, but I was only able to use a crosstab query to do one program at a time (i.e. I could get it to total just BusDriverHrs, but not other columns). It also didn't sort by name, so it ended up essentially giving me a total row as it's own column.

I'm pretty new to Access, so I might be missing something obvious, but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Options: 1) build aggregate query and use that as source for report; 2) use report Sorting  & Grouping features with aggregate calc in textbox. This is really quite basic Access functionality that any introductory tutorial book should cover. Referential integrity is irrelevant to this issue but why doesn't it have RI activated? There is no code provided for analysis and question is not really suited to SO.

Comment: CROSSTAB query would not seem to be appropriate for this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for responding to this. I think using an aggregate query will work. Given the terminology, I was able to find a video that is quite helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RiCqNtLz88